# delete in tableView

Tags: iphone

I just add this methods in .h file :

```
- (IBAction)EditTable:(id)sender;
```

- (IBAction)DeleteButtonAction:(id)sender;

and in .m file :

- (IBAction)DeleteButtonAction:(id)sender{
  [tableList removeLastObject];
  [Table reloadData];
  }
- (IBAction) EditTable:(id)sender{

  if(self.editing)

  {

  ```
  [super setEditing:NO animated:NO];
  [Table setEditing:NO animated:NO];
  [Table reloadData];
  [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
  [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];
  ```

  }

  else
  {

  ```
  [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];
  [Table setEditing:YES animated:YES];
  [Table reloadData];
  [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
  [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
  ```

  }

}

when I run the program and click the delete button (red button) the program is stop !
whats the problem ? please any help ?

---

you are evil :(

OK, again my code in .h file is :

```
- (IBAction)EditTable:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)DeleteButtonAction:(id)sender;
```

and in .m file is :

```
- (IBAction)DeleteButtonAction:(id)sender{
    [tableList removeLastObject];
    [Table reloadData];
}
- (IBAction) EditTable:(id)sender{

  if(self.editing)

{
[super setEditing:NO animated:NO];
[Table setEditing:NO animated:NO];
[Table reloadData];
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];
}
else
{
[super setEditing:YES animated:YES];
[Table setEditing:YES animated:YES];
[Table reloadData];
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
} }
```

when I run the program and click the delete button (red button) the program is crash ! whats the problem ? please any help ?

Comment: -1 for lazy formatting and non-adherence of common objc style. If you want help, at least make it easy to read your code!

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong then you want to delete the cell of the tableView when delete button is clicked....

You need to call one other method of tableview:

```
//To Delete the Data
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    // Updates the appearance of the Edit|Done button as necessary.
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [tblViewBM setEditing:editing animated:YES];
    // Disable the add button while editing.
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:
(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

//Use your Array from which you need to delete the data.
  NSMutableDictionary *dict=(NSMutableDictionary *)[appDel.BookMarkAry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  type=[dict valueForKey:@"type"];

  [appDel.BookMarkAry removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


  [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


  [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 } 
}
```

I am sure this will Definately help you to delete the cell with data from array also.