# How to delete multiple rows in table view?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [select multiple rows from uitableview and delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954393/select-multiple-rows-from-uitableview-and-delete)

I am developing an application which requires the ability to select multiple rows and delete them. I placed the checkboxes in the rows to mark them for deletion. but every time, the last row is selected. How can I select multiple rows?

Comment: In what condition you are trying to do this?

Comment: Duplicates: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954393/) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727302/) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949488/) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973756/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign checked and unchecked rows by

```
 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

     UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

     if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {

         selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

     } else if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {

         selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
     }
 }
```

for checking multiple rows.

While deleting them, check for

```
 UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark
```

and remove those rows that are checked.

Comment: The problem with this method is that the tableview reuses these cells. So a selected cell can replace an unselected cell any time the user scrolls up and down. This will lead to deletion of unintended rows.

Comment: @Deepak: Oh. Is it ? Wow. Thanks for the comment man. Any modifications necessary ?